# SQL Server Management Studio creates 18456 login error using registered server group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, connections, central-management-server

I have been using ["Local Server Groups" registration](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/one-weird-trick-for-managing-a-bunch-of-servers/) for quite a while now with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

I have created a group with 5 registered servers. They are registered using SQL authentication with the same login. That login has the same default database set on each of those servers. I can successfully connect to that group and query.

Today I changed the last server in the list of the registered servers group and changed it's connection details from "default database" to a specific database name that is different (*1) than the default database used for the other registered servers. It is assured that the login / password is correct, the login has access to the default and explicitly configured databases and all the databases exist.

**Edit 1**: I meanwhile figured out that it does not matter at all which database is configured for the connection, as long as there is something else configured other than "default db" the error comes - even if the configured db is the same as the default database, just typed explicitly.)

Since that moment, a SQL Alert for error 18456(=invalid login), that is configured to raise on each of the servers, showed up when connecting to the group for the FIRST server in the list. However, this alert definitely is WRONG because the connection was successfully established for all registered servers and I can query the databases as expected.

After deleting this first server from the list of registered servers, the same wrong login error alert 18456 showed up again only for the (new) first registered server in the group.

When I changed all the registered servers in the group back to use the default database for connect, this behavior disappeared.

I looked for a similar bug description but found nothing. Does anyone have any experience or reasons for this?

**Details about SSMS:**

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.50.6220.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        10.50.6000.34
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.18282
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.5485
Operating System                        6.1.7601
```

**Error log details:**

> Date      09.05.2016 16:38:52 Log     SQL Server (Current - 08.05.2016
> 23:59:00)
>
> Source        Logon
>
> Message Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
>
> Date      09.05.2016 16:38:52 Log     SQL Server (Current - 08.05.2016
> 23:59:00)
>
> Source        Logon
>
> Message Login failed for user 'xxx'. Reason: Failed to open the
> explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 1.2.3.4]

**EDIT 2:**

Even if all registered servers have "default database" selected but the login's configured default database on one (not the first) of the registered servers is different, then the same behavior shows up - the error is raised for the first server in the list.

Comment: And sorry it's unclear but does that error occur on the server that you changed the registration, or a different server (like the first one in the list), or all servers? (I was about to test this but [need to swap VMs for some strange reason](https://twitter.com/AaronBertrand/status/729686967902932992/photo/1)).

Comment: The error comes always for the first server in the list of registered. If I remove it, it comes for the next in the list that became the first one. It never comes for the server with the different database or where the login has ha different default db configured on. After playing around and putting everything BACK to how it used to be before, that error now ALWAYS comes for the first server in the list, although all servers are configured with DEFAULT DATABASE... AND although connection and query works fine. It's weird.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess you have not been able to reproduce this? It's still an issue for me and I still have to keep the invalid login Alerts disabled because of this behavior.

Comment: I have not, but I have no reason to use such an ancient version of SSMS, either... :-)

Comment: This definitely does not sound like normal behavior, 38 definitely means a database was inaccessible - do you have any databases offline, set to auto-close, snapshots, single user, restoring, or in recovery? Any databases that have been removed, renamed, or denied access? What does profiler tell you happens during connection (it might reveal a database name for example)?

Comment: For all DBS: is_auto_close_on=0,state_desc=ONLINE, user_access_desc=MULTI_USER; Snapshot_isolation_state (if you meant this=)=1 for some DBs, but never for the ones in the Registered servers Connection props. Renamed, I do not know, but no registration has a wrong database name and no user has a wrong default db name setting. Still a multiserver query WORKS perfectly and returns the correct Database names. Profiler shows up the same failed login message as in the question (in advance of succesfully logging in and returning results). And still: login fails for first server in group only!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the issue is. Without direct access all I'd be able to do is throw out a bunch of quasi-educated guesses.

Comment: The Invalid Login always happens for master. Does not make any difference what default_db the login has or what explicit db the reg. server has as in the conn.props. No difference if the used login is sysadmin or has is user of master. This is so strange! 
Alright, however thanks so far, I will keep this thing listening for someone in future who has the same issues.

Comment: Are you using a CMS?  Does this query show the expected list of servers?  `SELECT si.name FROM msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal si` ? It might be there is an old or incorrect entry in the list.